# Which one is more precise: Phase locked loop or log the waveform then do sliding FFT?

Tags: experimental-technique, signal-processing, experimental-technology

I have an experimental confusion. I am using an interferometer to monitor the movement of a translation stage by monitoring the intensity of the coaxis interference pattern of the He-Ne laser.

Basically I get a frequncy-modulated sine waveform by logging the intensity of the interference pattern when moving the translation stage. I have two choices：a) use a phase locked loop circuit to get the real-time frequency of this sine wave. b) log the waveform in real time and then analyze it afterwards.

Due to the measurement equipment (NI-DAQmax usb 6229) I have, the b) option is much easier for me. I already have the phase locked loop circuit whcih gives me the number of digital pulses being proportional to the frequency. But I can't count it with a reliable time resolution because of the trigger issue.

I am thinking does these two options supply the same resolution in practice?

**Update:** Actually there is a third choice c): log the output of the PLL ciruit in real time and then count it afterwards. Honestly, I have to admit, I want to log the waveform in real time if choice b) is good enough. I don't trust the PLL ciruit somehow.:(

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the bandwidth to count a digital pulse train that's at approximately your signal frequency, then you *definitely* don't have the bandwidth to log enough of your analog signal that you can post-analyze it in a meaningful way.  Borrow (or invest in) an oscilloscope to make sure you're measuring what you think you're measuring.

Consider adding a "period doubler," which generates an output pulse on every other input pulse, to the digital output of your phase-locked loop. You can chain period doublers until the output is slow enough for your DAQ to count. There are fast, few-component examples of period doublers in *The Art Of Electronics* and similar textbooks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually the bandwidth of the NI-DAQ is high enough to count the digital pulse train. The difficulty is how to count it using a reliable time resolution. I can count it continuously, or add a software-based timestamp to the count at a certain software-based time resolution, but the reliability is important to me, and I can't trigger it by external trigger or add hardware-based timestamp.

Comment: I have an oscilloscope which is good enough. Then I come to the same confusion, if I measure the waveform and analyze it afterwards, is the resollution comparable to the PLL cuit?

Comment: My comment about bandwidth applies also to clock stability. If you don't trust your DAQ to count digital pulses with reliable time resolution, why do you trust it to take analog samples with reliable time resolution? But perhaps I am misunderstanding some feature of your setup.

Comment: The time resolution I can get is not reliable because it's based on the reaction time of software on PC and the time when the PC read data from the buffer of the NI-DAQ: use a while loop, count the rising edge in dt. The clock on PC and NI-DAQ is independent. It's not possible for me to supply a hardware based dt when counting the edge due to the limitation of the setup.